# AutoMoq an abstract class with specific constructor

Tags: autofixture, automoq

Is there a way to setup AutoFixture.AutoMoq such that when mocking an abstract class it uses a specific constructor?

I need to test the implementation done in my abstract class. However, I do need to use one specific constructor.

```
public abstract class A
{
    public A(IQueryable q) // I need to use this
    { /*...*/ }
}
```

Regards,

---

EDIT:

I am trying to use something like below but still does not work.
The class is abstract so I need to mock it, but I need a very specific constructor.

How to tell AutoMoq that when mocking A please do not use either MockConstructorQuery or GreedyMockConstructorQuery. Just use QueryableParamConstructorQuery.

fixture.Customize(
        new ConstructorCustomization(typeof(A),
          new QueryableParamConstructorQuery()));

Answer (score 0):

If you need a particular constructor, you can pass the argument list when you create the test double:

```
var q = fixture.Create<IQueryable>();
var a = new Mock<A>(q).Object;
```

---

If you need to change AutoFixture's behaviour to always use this particular constructor, you can do something like this:

```
fixture.Register(q => new Mock<A>(q));
```

Comment: That is great but I was actually looking for fixture.Create<A>(q) or somehow fixture.Create<A>() knows that I want the constructor that receives a queryable or a list and not e.g. the one that receives a db conection string. I am a beginner here.